# Testing mouse event listener added using ref in React functional component

Tags: reactjs, testing, dom, jestjs, react-hooks

Hi I have a functional component as shown below:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const SomeComponent = ({ prop1, ...otherProps}) => {
  const divRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    divRef.current.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownFunc);
  }, []);

  const mouseDownFunc = () => {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', (el) => {
        // call some parent function
    });
  }

  return (
    <div
        className='test-div'
        ref={ divRef }>
    </div>
  );
};
```

How do I test a react functional component wherein addEventListener is added using ref inside useEffect which when triggered calls mouseDownFunc.
I'm new to react jest testing, little confused on how to do it.

Comment: What did you try? Is there a specific reason why you used addEventListener instead of React events?

Answer (score 2):

Testing this sort of component can be tricky, but using `@testing-library/react` I think I was able to come up with something useful.

I did have to make some changes to your component to expose the API a bit, and I also made some changes so that it stops listening to the events on `mouseup` which may not be the specific event you want.

Here's the modified component:

```js
// MouseDownExample.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default ({ onMouseMoveWhileDown }) => {
  const [x, setX] = useState(null);
  const [listening, setListening] = useState();

  // Replaced with mouse move function, should make sure we're unlistening as well
  useEffect(() => {
    if (listening) {
      const onMouseMove = (event) => {
        // call some parent function
        onMouseMoveWhileDown(event);

        console.log(event.clientX);

        // purely for testing purposes
        setX(event.clientX);
      };
      const onMouseUp = (event) => {
        // stop listening on mouse up
        // - you should pick whatever event you want to stop listening
        // - this is global so it also stops when the mouse is outside the box
        setListening(false);
      };
      document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
      document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
        document.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
      };
    }
  }, [listening, onMouseMoveWhileDown]);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "red",
        width: 200,
        height: 200
      }}
      className="test-div"
      onMouseDown={() => {
        // moved this inline, so no ref
        setListening(true);
      }}
    >
      X Position: {x}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I called out in comments the main differences.

And here's an example test:

```js
// MouseDownExample.test.js
import React from "react";
import { fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import MouseDownExample from "./MouseDownExample";

it("shouldn't trigger onMouseMoveWhileDown when mouse isn't down", () => {
  const onMouseMoveWhileDown = jest.fn();
  const { container } = render(
    <MouseDownExample onMouseMoveWhileDown={onMouseMoveWhileDown} />
  );

  // Note: normally I would use `screen.getByRole` but divs don't have a useful role
  const subject = container.firstChild;

  fireEvent.mouseMove(
    document,
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent
    {
      clientX: 200
    }
  );
  // hasn't gone down yet
  expect(onMouseMoveWhileDown).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

  fireEvent.mouseDown(subject);
  fireEvent.mouseUp(subject);

  // went down then up before moving
  fireEvent.mouseMove(document, {
    clientX: 200
  });
  expect(onMouseMoveWhileDown).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});

it("should trigger onMouseMoveWhileDown when mouse is down", () => {
  const onMouseMoveWhileDown = jest.fn();
  const { container } = render(
    <MouseDownExample onMouseMoveWhileDown={onMouseMoveWhileDown} />
  );

  // Note: normally I would use `screen.getByRole` but divs don't have a useful role
  const subject = container.firstChild;

  fireEvent.mouseDown(subject);
  fireEvent.mouseMove(document, {
    clientX: 200
  });

  expect(onMouseMoveWhileDown).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    expect.objectContaining({ clientX: 200 })
  );
});
```

What's happening here, is we're rendering the component, then firing events to ensure the `onMouseMoveWhileDown` function prop is called when we expect.

We have to do `expect.objectContaining` rather than just the object because it's called with a `MouseEvent` which contains other properties.

Another test we might want to add is an unmount test to ensure the listeners are no longer triggering events.

You can look at/experiment with this [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mouse-down-move-kpo9i?file=/src/MouseDownExample.test.js) with this component and the tests. Hope this helps

Comment: If you have any issues with the modifications made, lmk and we can work that out/try to figure out how to test without the changes